# Did speech recognition services stop working in Oreo?

Tags: android, android-service, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, android-8.0-oreo

I implemented a background service Speech recognition in my application. It stops working after a few seconds (In Pixcel and Nexus devices) due to Oreo OS does not support the background services. This service is the main feature of the application. It should continue running in Android OS 8 too. Please provide me a solution for it.

This link will explain about the back ground services restriction in Oreo 8 android os: **https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#migration**

Answer (score 0):

You can check on this article : [Keep those background Services working when targeting Android Oreo](https://android.jlelse.eu/keep-those-background-services-working-when-targeting-android-oreo-sdk-26-cbf6cc2bdb7f)

> "The JobIntentService works in the same way as a Service however it
>   enqueues the work into the JobScheduler on compatible Android targets.
>   This means you can easily convert your Services and IntentServices
>   into a JobIntentService and keep the same functionality."

And it will handle older Android versions compatibility automatically : [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html)

> "When running on Android O or later, the work will be dispatched as a
>   job via JobScheduler.enqueue. When running on older versions of the
>   platform, it will use Context.startService."

Comment: I already Implemented JobIntent Service . Speech recognition  not listen after few seconds . In pixcel or nexus devices this service stop automaticallly